# Why value of input here at reactjs is undefined?

Tags: reactjs

**I want to change `state` by the value of input but it is `undefined`.
It should work, the value is for every HTML tag so what is wrong with my code??**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: " "
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      firstName: event.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Firstname"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <h1>{this.state.value}</h1>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You haven't bind `this`. Try changing `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`

Comment: yesss ...thnks sir

Comment: so does binding the function solved your issue?

Comment: yes of course..@Vishnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `value` stored in your state, so *it is* undefined, and you do not correctly bind `this` to your handler. Output `this.state.firstName` instead:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: " "
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      firstName: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Firstname"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <h1>{this.state.firstName}</h1>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit angry-sun-srldj]

Answer (score 0):

First try to bind **this** for handleChange using an arrow function. Also use the state variable to set the  value property of the input .

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-qmyw5

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: " "
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      firstName: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Firstname"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.firstName}
        />
        <h1>{this.state.firstName}</h1>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```